# Output for finding element using binary search not getting as expected?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

> Given a sorted array.We need to find the element x in the array using binary search.

MyApproach:

I implemented the binary search as follows.

Checked 3 cases 1)Whether the middle element==x

2)Whether the element is less than the middle element.Then, reduce the search space to end=mid-1

3)Whether the element is less than the middle element.Then, reduce the search space to start=mid+1

I used start<=end so that in case either some elements are left or the start==end.Then,in that case only one element is left.

I implemented this but I havent got the ExpectedOutput

> Can anyone guide me why?
>   @Edit

```
My Main Method


public static void main(String s[])
 {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of testcases");
    int T=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");

        int n=sc.nextInt();

        int ar[]=new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            //System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");

            ar[i]=sc.nextInt(); //the elements should be entered in  sorted order
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the element to be searched");

        int x=sc.nextInt();
        int a=binarySearch(ar,x);
        System.out.println("the element is at index"+"::"+a);


     }

    sc.close();

}

public static int binarySearch(int[] ar,int x)
{
    int start=0,end=ar.length-1;
    int mid=0;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        mid=start+(end-start)/2; //To avoid Overflow
        if(ar[mid]==x)
         return mid;
        else if(x<ar[mid])
        {
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else 
        {
            start=mid+1;


        }
    }
    return -1;
}

Input         Element Searched      ExpectedOutput    MyOutput

5             8                      3                -1 

6

7 

8
```

Comment: Try running your application with some System.out.prinln() instructions on you "if"s and "elses". Maybe you can figure this out on your own. Check the "mid", "start", "end" variables.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you sure the input parameters are what you say they are?

Comment: It works fine for me for the values specified by you. You should try to dry run or debug your code and check the values of end, mid and start variables.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, can you post the input array?

Comment: Input array is same:I have taken input from the user.I also have dry run the code and have got correct output but not when I am doing on eclipseId.

Comment: If this algorithm is giving you the correct results when you run it one way, but incorrect results when you run it a different way, the problem isn't in your algorithm.  The problem is somewhere else, outside the code you've posted.

Comment: @Jasonarora post your Main method where you get the input and call this method

Comment: @Thanga Edited the code

Comment: @ajb I am not able to identify outside the algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important thing is, this algorithm will work only on sorted array.** Issue is as below

In the below code you have put `ar[i]` instead of `ar[j]`

```
 for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            //System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");

            ar[i]=sc.nextInt(); //the elements should be entered in  sorted order
        }
```